# Prove that the matrix is invertible.

Tags: matrices

You are given a matrix 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -p(a) \\
        p(a) & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
where p is a non-constant polynomial with real coefficients.

Prove that the matrix is invertible for every $ a \in \mathbb{R} $ and every $ a \in \mathbb{C} $.

Answer (score 2):

case $a\in \mathbb{R}$ :
$$det(M) = 1+p^2(a)> 0$$ so $M$ is invertible

case $a \in \mathbb{C}$ :

If $p(a)=a$ and $a=i$ then $det(M)=0$ and $M$ is not invertible